# (jQuery) What is wrong with methods such as .append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, efficiency

**tl;dr:** What is wrong with the efficiency of methods such as .append() and what can be alternatives to this?

**Explanation:**
Hello everyone. I occasionally have to build A/B tests for websites, which means that i have to change sites using only jQuery(or javascript of course) to alter appearances and functionalities of websites. This means no 'hard'-html/css or the likes. Now i'm pretty much the only one with the slightest knowledge of javascript that works here, so i don't get much peer reviews. Now we are working with a customer and their developer sends me this feedback:

'jQuery isn't used optimally by appending seperate/loose items into the DOM'.

An example of this is an accordeon item i added to the site, by typing (something along the lines of):

```
$('#site_container').append('<div id="container"><div id="container_click">Content to click on</div></div id="container_expand">Content to be shown when expanded</div></div>');
$('#container_click').click(function(){//animate to height function here});
```

Now i've already tried to do my own research, and i know typing an entire element with it's content in 1 string is not as secure as making an object and then adding attributes to that object. For a temporary test however, i do not think this is such a big issue, since they only tend to live for a week or 2.

I do realise the solution feels a bit flimsy, but i do not really see a different approach.

**Now my question is:** What does the other developer mean with optimally? Is there a big part of jQuery i'm missing? Is there a way to approach problems like these more efficiently?

Comment: Why not just ask the developer himself what he meant with "*optimally*"? We neither know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they probably meant is that manipulating the DOM is slow and that you can avoid injecting HTML through jQuery.

What you can do, instead, is to have A/B variants both in your original HTML. Then, you hide the B variant by default, and switch from A to B by simply hiding the one and showing the other.

An even better alternative is to have two HTML templates, one for A variant, another one for B. This way, you don't even need to rely on JavaScript.

---

Performance-wise, I'm not sure if you need to take in consideration their remark. Unless you're doing *a lot* of DOM manipulation, you `.append()` maybe slows down the page by a few milliseconds or even microseconds. Unless you've profiled the app and determined that your `.append()` is the actual bottleneck, don't bother.

You may, on the other hand, be interested by [43,439 reasons to use append() correctly](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly/) blog article and by [.append VS .html VS .innerHTML performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18394159/240613) answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, we do the tests for customers, and we never have any acces to their html. We work with A/B programs that can only inject javascript, so that is my limitation.

Comment: How can jQuery avoid the DOM when appending an element to the DOM?

Comment: @Rob: see the last link in my answer: in their particular case, `innerHTML` appears faster than `.append`.

Comment: @MainMa You said "you can avoid injecting HTML through jQuery" and I asked how does jQuery avoid the DOM when inserting HTML into the DOM. I'm not asking about speed.

Comment: @Rob: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm questioning your statement. You are saying jQuery doesn't use the DOM when injecting HTML into a web page but that's impossible.

Comment: @Rob, `jquery.append` uses the DOM to inject HTML. What MainMa is saying is that there are other strategies available besides injecting HTML, and thus avoiding the DOM..

Comment: @cbojar Which led to my question, how does one inject HTML into a web page without using the DOM?

Comment: @Rob You don't inject it. Instead, you can do as MainMa suggested and have both parts in the HTML already, then use jQuery to set a class to indicate which will be show. Your CSS would control what shows up based on that class.

Comment: @cbojar Ok. I got lost between his first sentence and the topic because I started thinking he was saying jQuery inserts HTML without using the DOM.

Comment: @Rob: I made my answer community wiki. Feel free to improve it if you want to.

Comment: @MainMa No, you're fine. I just got lost in the details.